# How to update database within for loop?

Tags: php

This seems like it should be so obvious, but it's driving me crazy! What I have is a for loop that outputs a number (10 in this case) of random cards and updates the generated list into the database, but for some reason I can only get it to update the last generated card. What am I doing wrong?

Just FYI, $card was declared in admin/random.php (it pulls up a random deck and a random number, so in this case it pulls up "testdeck01" or "testdeck12", etc)

```
$select=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='name'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
$new=$row['new'];
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    include ("admin/random.php");
    $cards=$card.", ";
    echo $cards;
    $newcards=$new.$cards;
        $update = "UPDATE `members` SET new='$newcards' WHERE name='name'";
        if (mysqli_query($connect, $update)) {
    }       
}
echo "<br><br>".$update;
}
```

When I echo $cards I get exactly what I want to see in the database - "testdeck02, testdeck09, testdeck04, testdeck15,"... etc

So I tried to just set the column "new" to $cards, but it only added the last card to the database, so that is when I tried to grab the database value and add each card to it by creating $newcards, but I'm still only getting the final value. What am I doing wrong??

This is the current output I get:

```
testdeck14, testdeck07, testdeck10, testdeck14, testdeck09, testdeck14, testdeck10, testdeck08, testdeck03, testdeck14, 

UPDATE `members` SET new='testdeck14, ' WHERE name='name'
```

I EXPECT it to look more like this:

```
testdeck14, testdeck07, testdeck10, testdeck14, testdeck09, testdeck14, testdeck10, testdeck08, testdeck03, testdeck14, 

UPDATE `members` SET new='testdeck14, testdeck07, testdeck10, testdeck14, testdeck09, testdeck14, testdeck10, testdeck08, testdeck03, testdeck14, ' WHERE name='name'
```

If I were to refresh the page, this is what I get:

```
testdeck11, testdeck05, testdeck05, testdeck06, testdeck09, testdeck02, testdeck03, testdeck07, testdeck08, testdeck15, 

UPDATE `members` SET new='testdeck14, testdeck15, ' WHERE name='name'
```

Comment: You've hardcoded the `WHERE` condition, `... WHERE name='name'";`, probably that's why.

Comment: I don't want every instance of "new" to be updated. Only where name = 'name'...

Comment: maybe it updates same row in the whole loop

Comment: Just for the debugging purpose, `echo` out the query. Do `echo $update . '<br />';` inside the `for` loop and see what you're getting.

Comment: That's helpful, in that I see a little more what is happening, but it's still only grabbing the last card and not the full set of 10 cards... :/

Comment: So keeping [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664663/how-to-update-database-within-for-loop#comment70527820_41664663) in mind, please edit your question and show the **current** `UPDATE` and **expected** `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: is the value you want in the database a comma seperated list? (ex. "testdeck02, testdeck09, testdeck04")

Comment: I've updated the question to show the ouput and what I see on the page. @BizzyBob Yes. I want the database to be a comma separated list.

Comment: @Anna And what's the expected `UPDATE` queries?

Comment: The expected update query is the 10 random cards generated. They show up great if I simply echo $cards, but if I try to use $cards in the database query it still only updates the last card and not all 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you really want to do is update a single database row, with a single value.  Therefore, you don't want to have your `UPDATE` happening within the loop!

> Also, your output 'looks' correct on the screen, but it is really 10
>   separate prints to the screen.  Your `$cards` variable never contains
>   all of the text at once.  That's why the database is only getting the
>   last value!

So, lets use the `$cards` variable to store the entire list of all the cards like this:

`$cards = $cards . $card . ', ';`  or the shorter syntax `$cards .= $card . ', ';`

Then get your update out of the loop, so it would look something like this:

```
$cards = ''; // will contain comma separated list

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    include("admin/random.php");
    $cards .= $card . ", "; // builds list
}

$newcards = $new . $cards;
$update = "UPDATE `members` SET new='$newcards' WHERE name='name'";
```

It does make the code harder to follow when you're including the file within the loop.  Say your `random.php` has a function called `getRandomCard()`.  You could do the `include` the file only once, then call the function multiple times like this:

```
include("admin/random.php");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $card = newRandomCard();
    $cards .= $card . ", "; // builds list
}
```

Comment: This answer is very close to what I was thinking. Nice! ;-)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed!! I tried something similar before and it didn't work (I think I put the empty $cards inside the for loop or something like that). Thank you so much!!!!!